# how do I speed up this apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know this runs slowly because it makes multiple calls to the API. My understanding is that I could be able to make a single call, store the data in an array, then make only one other call to send the data back to the sheet, or "batch" these calls somehow. I am unsure of how to do either.

```
//function to display artist info on a search form

function searchRecord() {

  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var infosheet= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Artist Info");
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Database");
    
  var str       = infosheet.getRange("Y4").getValue(); //cell populated by artist name dropdown
  var values    = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var valuesFound=false;

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var rowValue = values[i];
    if (rowValue[0] == str) { 

//pulls from Database to populate the info form

  infosheet.getRange("D6").setValue(rowValue[0]); //ARTIST NAME
  infosheet.getRange("D7").setValue(rowValue[1]); //CONTACT NAME
  infosheet.getRange("F10").setValue(rowValue[5]); //CELL PHONE
  infosheet.getRange("F11").setValue(rowValue[6]); //EMAIL
  infosheet.getRange("F12").setValue(rowValue[7]); //MSGR LINK
  infosheet.getRange("I10").setValue(rowValue[18]); //CITY
  infosheet.getRange("I11").setValue(rowValue[19]); //COUNTY
  infosheet.getRange("I12").setValue(rowValue[20]); //STATE

//there are approx. 100 more lines exactly like the ones above, this is just a snippet

return; }}

if(valuesFound==false){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("No record found!");}}
```

I barely know what I'm doing here, and I'm not sure what to try, as the cells that must be populated are not in an array and the cells to pull from are not in order. I have reviewed similar questions but can't figure out how to apply those solutions here.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Your title is `how do I speed up this apps script?`. In this case, your showing script works fine except for the process cost of the script. Is my understanding correct? But, you also say `I barely know what I'm doing here, and I'm not sure what to try, as the cells that must be populated are not in an array and the cells to pull from are not in order.`. So, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Yes, the whole thing takes at least 30 seconds to execute. I've only included part of the script in my post, there are about 100 more lines as mentioned above. My question is how can it be made faster? From what I've read, there is a better way to do this but I do not know how.

Comment: If the data range contains only values, no formulas, replace the value in `values` and then write back the entire `values` array using [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Answer (score 0):

I think you (and folks in the comments) have already correctly identified what's slowing things down. Each call to `setValue` takes a lot of time, so if you have over a hundred it'll definitely slow things down.

In most cases, if you are writing many values to a spreadsheet, you almost always want to use `setValues` instead of several `setValue` statements. As the name implies, `setValues` allows you to write many values to a spreadsheet, whereas `setValue` only allows you to write 1 value to a given cell. The only consideration is that `setValues` only allows you to write to cells within a contiguous rectangle of cells. In other words if there are cells in between the cells you want to write to that you don't want to be affected, you may be forced to use more than one `setValues` (or potentially more than one `setValue` depending on what your spreadsheet looks like).

I don't know what your spreadsheet looks like, but I see that you are writing to cells D6 and D7 and then jumping to cells F10, F11, and F12. Assuming you absolutely do not want to overwrite any of the cells in between these ranges, you could re-write your code like so:

```
function searchRecord() {

  var myGooglSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var infosheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Artist Info");
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("Database");

  var str = infosheet.getRange("Y4").getValue(); //cell populated by artist name dropdown
  var values = datasheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var valuesFound = false;

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var rowValue = values[i];
    if (rowValue[0] == str) {

      //pulls from Database to populate the info form

      infosheet.getRange(6, 4, 2).setValues([[rowValue[0]], [rowValue[1]]]);
      infosheet.getRange(10, 6, 3).setValues([[rowValue[5]], [rowValue[6]], [rowValue[7]]]);
      infosheet.getRange(10, 8, 3).setValues([[rowValue[18]], [rowValue[19]], [rowValue[20]]]);
      //there are approx. 100 more lines exactly like the ones above, this is just a snippet

      return;
    }
  }

  if (valuesFound == false) {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("No record found!");
  }
}
```

Going from 8 to 3 calls, which is an improvement. If you can overwrite the cells in between, you can cut that down to 1 call (if possible, you could also overwrite the cells in the middle with whatever values are already there, so the user doesn't notice any difference).

Note that `setValues` expects an array of arrays that represent what the spreadsheet looks like. So if you so something like this `setValues([[2,3], [3,4]])`, it'll look something like this in the spreadsheet:

```
_________
| 2 | 3 |
---------
| 3 | 4 |
---------
```

Note that the inner arrays represent rows and the elements within that array represent columns, the other array contains the entire grid of data.

All that being said, just looking at what your script is doing, it sort of looks like you might be able to just accomplish things with spreadsheet formulas, using something like `vlookup` or `index + match` to find the data you need to populate those fields based on a search key.

Comment: Yes! I do not have a "contiguous rectangle of cells." That is why I didn't think it was that straightforward. Formulas won't work because the form also serves to overwrite the Database using a different script (which your suggestion will also help). Thanks so much!

Comment: Awesome, if my answer helped, please mark it as accepted, that'll help others find it if they run into a similar issue.